# Cannot access Azure VM Scaleset ip address externally

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-scale-set

I have created a Virtual Machine Scaleset in Azure

This scaleset is made up of 5 VMs

There is a public ip

When I do a ping on my public ip I get no response, nor do I get a response with the full name, e.g.

myapp.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com

Is there something I have missed?

I am wondering if I have to add my machine's IP somewhere?

I am trying to remote into the machines within the scaleset eventually!

This scaleset will be used for azure service fabric

Paul

Comment: Can you share more information about the services you're using? You have a public IP address, and a single scale set? Do you have a virtual network and load balancer setup as well?

Answer (score 2):

If you deploy your scale set with "public IP per VM", then each VM gets its own public IP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-networking#public-ipv4-per-virtual-machine. However, this is not the default in the portal. In the portal, the default is to create a load balancer in front of the scale set with a single public IP on the LB (today, at least; no guarantee it will stay this way). It also comes with NAT rules configured to allow RDP/SSH on ports 50000 and above. They won't necessarily be contiguous, though (at least in the default configuration), so you will need to examine the NAT rules on the load balancer to see which ports are relevant. Once you do, you should be able to do `ssh -p <port-from-nat-rule> <public-ip>` to ssh in (or similar in your RDP client for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

> When I do a ping on my public ip I get no response

Azure does not support ping.

For test, you can use RDP/SSH public IP address with different ports to test the connection.

Are you create VMSS with Azure marketplace? If yes, the Azure LB will configured.

If the load balancer created by your self, please check LB [probes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview), backend pools(all vms should in that backend pools), load balancer rules and NAT rules.

Also you can configure [log analytics for Azure load balancer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log) to monitor it.